# How can i implement a vector.insert like method for my custom vector class?

Tags: c++, class, vector, stl, insert

i have made a custom class to implement a std::vector.
My class has Forward iterator support. I'd like to know how I can implement a vector.insert like method that allows me to insert an element at any position inside the vector.
I can't use allocator, but i'd like to know if the insert method can be done with iterators and, if it is possible, how can it be done?

Comment: It means that i made a class that does the same things the std::vector does.

Comment: Because it's a university project and i'm not allowed to use stl containers, the "vector" i created is made to store triples ( made with a struct )

Comment: What have you tried so far? We aren't going to write your university project for you.

Comment: I'm not asking you to made me the project... i'm asking how to implement a insert method with forward iterators i already made...

Comment: If you need a list of what i have already made, here it is: constructor, destructor, copy constructor, template copy constructor, operator[], const operator[], operator=, get_size, get capacity, push_back, forward iterator, forward const iterator.

Comment: @JesperJuhl  how can i do that? it's pretty long 435 line only the class

Comment: To implement `insert` you need to move/copy all elements post the insertion point one element (possibly allocating new memory and moving all members), then insert the new element in the "hole" you just made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement `insert` you need to move/copy all elements post the insertion point one element (possibly allocating new memory and moving all members if your internal storage is not large enough), then insert the new element in the "hole" you just made.

Note that this (of course) invalidates existing iterators.